# Spanning a group of subspaces with minimal possible group of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

calling out for the linear algebra masters out there with the following challenge:

> Let $V$ be a vector sapce over the field $F$ with $dim(V) = n$. Let
>   $B_1,...,B_n$ be subspaces of $V$ with $dim(B_i)=n-1$ (hyperplanes). 
>  Assume
>   that for every $1 \leq i,j\leq n$, $i\neq j, dim(B_i\cap B_j) = n-2$ (meaning
>   that there are no two identicle hyperplanes). 
>  Define the set $G$ as a
>   set of vectors from $V$, so that for every $1\leq i\leq n$, $B_i$ has $n-1$
>   vectors from $G$, $G_i = \{g_i^1,...,g_i^{n-1}\}$, with $span\{G_i\}=B_i$. Of
>   course, $G$ is not unique.
>   I would like to find a set $G$ satisfying
>   the above condition with minimal size $k$, and find a closed form of $k$
>   as a function of $n$, and the dimensions of all the possible intersections of subspaces from
>   $\{B_1,...,B_n\}$.

For example, for $n=3$, assume that $dim(B_1\cap B_2)=dim(B_2\cap B_3)=dim(B_2\cap B_3)=1$, and $dim(B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3)=0$, then $k=3$.

However, if $dim(B_1\cap B_2)=dim(B_2\cap B_3)=dim(B_2\cap B_3)=1$, and $dim(B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3)=1$, then $k=4$. 

Thanks in advance!